# A noun for an official examining the body of the diseased making sure it was a natural death

Tags: word-request

Grandma passed away at home. A certain official with a few helpers were supposed to come from the government to our house and examine the body to make sure that it was a case of natural death. What's the right noun to describe the office of that official? Would "persecutor" fit the bill? Or, perhaps, "coroner"? Or some other noun?

Comment: What did you find for the definition of coroner?

Comment: @Davo: "a usually elected public officer who is typically not required to have specific medical qualifications and whose principal duty is to inquire by an inquest into the cause of any death which there is reason to suppose is not due to natural causes" (Webster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, a death has to be certified by a doctor (if the death occurred at home, it would be the deceased's *general practitioner*). Only if there is uncertainty about the cause of death would a *post-mortem [examination]* be carried out in hospital by a pathologist. If there is serious uncertainty (such as a possibility it was murder), an *inquest* is held, presided over by the coroner.

If the official procedures are different in your country, I don't know what the correct terms would be.

*Persecutor* is certainly not the word you want. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/persecute